# How to use AWS Glue / Spark to convert CSVs partitioned and split in S3 to partitioned and split Parquet

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-glue

In AWS Glue's catalog, I have an external table defined with partitions that looks roughly like this in S3 and partitions for new dates are added daily:

```
s3://my-data-lake/test-table/
    2017/01/01/
        part-0000-blah.csv.gz
        .
        .
        part-8000-blah.csv.gz
    2017/01/02/
        part-0000-blah.csv.gz
        .
        .
        part-7666-blah.csv.gz
```

How could I use Glue/Spark to convert this to parquet that is also partitioned by date and split across *n* files per day?. The examples don't cover partitioning or splitting or provisioning (how many nodes and how big). Each day contains a couple hundred GBs.

Because the source CSVs are not necessarily in the right partitions (wrong date) and are inconsistent in size, I'm hoping to to write to partitioned parquet with the right partition and more consistent size.

Answer (score 13):

Since the source CSV files are not necessarily in the right date, you could add to them additional information regarding collect date time (or use any date if already available):

```
{"collectDateTime": {
    "timestamp": 1518091828,
    "timestampMs": 1518091828116,
    "day": 8,
    "month": 2,
    "year": 2018
}}
```

Then your job could use this information in the output DynamicFrame and ultimately use them as partitions. Some sample code of how to achieve this:

```
from awsglue.transforms import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

import sys
import datetime

###
# CREATE THE NEW SIMPLIFIED LINE
##
def create_simplified_line(event_dict):

    # collect date time
    collect_date_time_dict = event_dict["collectDateTime"]

    new_line = {
        # TODO: COPY YOUR DATA HERE
        "myData": event_dict["myData"],
        "someOtherData": event_dict["someOtherData"],
        "timestamp": collect_date_time_dict["timestamp"],
        "timestampmilliseconds": long(collect_date_time_dict["timestamp"]) * 1000,
        "year": collect_date_time_dict["year"],
        "month": collect_date_time_dict["month"],
        "day": collect_date_time_dict["day"]
    }

    return new_line


###
# MAIN FUNCTION
##

# context
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

# fetch from previous day source bucket
previous_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

# build s3 paths
s3_path = "s3://source-bucket/path/year={}/month={}/day={}/".format(previous_date.year, previous_date.month, previous_date.day)

# create dynamic_frame
dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="s3", connection_options={"paths": [s3_path]}, format="json", format_options={}, transformation_ctx="dynamic_frame")

# resolve choices (optional)
dynamic_frame_resolved = ResolveChoice.apply(frame=dynamic_frame,choice="project:double",transformation_ctx="dynamic_frame_resolved")

# transform the source dynamic frame into a simplified version
result_frame = Map.apply(frame=dynamic_frame_resolved, f=create_simplified_line)

# write to simple storage service in parquet format
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=result_frame, connection_type="s3", connection_options={"path":"s3://target-bucket/path/","partitionKeys":["year", "month", "day"]}, format="parquet")
```

Did not test it, but the script is just a sample of how to achieve this and is fairly straightforward.

UPDATE

**1) As for having specific file sizes/numbers in output partitions**,

Spark's [coalesce and repartition](https://hackernoon.com/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4) features are not yet implemented in Glue's Python API (only in Scala).

You can convert your dynamic frame into a data frame and leverage Spark's [partition capabilities](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/FAQ_and_How_to.md#1-how-do-i-repartition-or-coalesce-my-output-into-more-or-fewer-files).

> **Convert to a dataframe and partition based on "partition_col"**
>
> partitioned_dataframe = datasource0.toDF().repartition(1)
>
> **Convert back to a DynamicFrame for further processing.**
>
> partitioned_dynamicframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(partitioned_dataframe,
>   glueContext, "partitioned_df")

The good news is that Glue has an interesting feature that if you have more than 50,000 input files per partition it'll automatically group them to you.

In case you want to specifically set this behavior regardless of input files number (**your case**), you may set the following `connection_options` while "creating a dynamic frame from options":

```
dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="s3", connection_options={"paths": [s3_path], 'groupFiles': 'inPartition', 'groupSize': 1024 * 1024}, format="json", format_options={}, transformation_ctx="dynamic_frame")
```

In the previous example, it would attempt to group files into 1MB groups.

It is worth mentioning that this is not the same as *coalesce*, but it may help if your goal is to reduce the number of files per partition.

**2) If files already exist in the destination, will it just safely add it (not overwrite or delete)**

Glue's default *[SaveMode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#save-modes)* for `write_dynamic_frame.from_options` is to **append**.

> When saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data/table already
>   exists, contents of the DataFrame are expected to be appended to
>   existing data.

**3) Given each source partition may be 30-100GB, what's a guideline for # of DPUs**

I'm afraid I won't be able to answer that. It depends on how fast it'll load your input files (size/number), your script's transformations, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the example script! I'll try it out and provide updates. Couple questions: (1) Is it possible for the output parquet to be split into 200MB files or _n_ files? (2) If files already exist in the destination, will it just safely add it (not overwrite or delete)? (3) Given each source partition may be 30-100GB, what's a guideline for # of DPUs?

Comment: I've updated the answer with your questions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Give us a feedback. Don't forget to mark as answered if this helped. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions so far.

Comment: I'm trying it now. For reading the csv.gz's, I'm finding I need to put each file into an array for ``connection_info['paths']`` as well as specify ``format_options['withHeader'] = True``. Otherwise nothing gets picked up. As a result, all fields are strings. What's the best approach for setting types? If I'm using a ``.toDF()`` call, would it make sense to Is it faster to add the columns by switching to a DataFrame and using spark sql ``withColumn`` or by using Glue's ``Map``?

Comment: Also if I do this using ``from_catalog`` for my data source and turn on job bookmarks, will it effectively do the same thing?

Comment: The `connection_info paths` option is indeed an array, but you should only need to specify partitions, not files. It should read each partition's files automatically. As for the fields types, Glue should be inferring them correctly. Are they correctly formatted on the csv files? Worth checking.

You could change to bookmarks and let the crawler infer the columns for you. Make sure to retrieve Glue's job, init and then commit it in your python code otherwise the bookmark won't work as expected. `job = Job(glueContext); job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args); ... script code here...; job.commit()`.

Comment: Glue documentation [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-dg.pdf).

Comment: Specifying by path will pick up all files within. Having a directory containing directories (specifying year=2018/month=3/day=1 works, but year=2018/month=3/ won't pick up day=1, day=2 within). The inferred types are all strings. Under connection_options I tried passing in ``inferSchema=True``. The crawler/catalog *does* infer the correct types.

Comment: Using ``spark.read`` instead of ``glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options`` seems to offer 4x performance and the schema is inferred. With Dynamic Frame I process 0.6 MB/s. With spark df, I get 2.4 MB/s (to read, add columns, write to parquet into S3). The source files are .csv.gz.

Comment: That's interesting. The Glue team has been constantly improving the service (which is relatively new) and we've noticed some notorious performance increases in the past month (March) while only using Glue's libraries (no vanilla spark whatsoever). You should gather some metrics and open a support ticket in the AWS console.

As for the paths not being picked up, you can iterate over all months, days and hours and add them to an array of paths. The empty ones will be skipped by Glue.

Comment: `repartition` and `coalesce` is now available in python glue: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-repartition

Answer (score -1):

Import the datetime library

```
import datetime
```

Split the timestamp based on partition conditions

```
now=datetime.datetime.now()
year= str(now.year)
```

`month= str(now.month)`

    `day= str(now.day)`

```
currdate= "s3:/Destination/"+year+"/"+month+"/"+day
```

Add the variable currdate in the path address in the writer class. The results will be patitioned parquet files.

Comment: Sorry, it's a little hard for me to follow how to use your suggestion. Assuming the source is read into a dynamic frame, this doesn't really address how to partition *and* split files. @leovrf helps with getting things to the right partition by specifying `partition_keys` as part of `connection_options`. However if I have 3 csv.gz's in a source partition with 3 days of data in each csv.gz, I end up with 3 parquet partitions with 3 files in each directory.